# "network_interface": conflicts with subnet_id

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating terraform on aws with below code:

```
    # Block Settings
    terraform {
      required_providers {
        aws = {
          source = "hashicorp/aws"
        }
      }
    }

    # Provider
    provider "aws" {
      profile = "default"
      region = "us-east-2"
    }

    # VPC
    resource "aws_vpc" "TF_VPC" {
      cidr_block = "170.31.0.0/16"
    }

    # Subnets
    resource "aws_subnet" "TF_Subnet1" {
      vpc_id     = aws_vpc.TF_VPC.id
      cidr_block = "170.31.1.0/24"
      availability_zone = "us-east-2a"
    }

    resource "aws_subnet" "TF_Subnet2" {
      vpc_id     = aws_vpc.TF_VPC.id
      cidr_block = "170.31.2.0/24"
      availability_zone = "us-east-2b"
    }
    # Security Group
    resource "aws_security_group" "TF_SG" {
      vpc_id = aws_vpc.TF_VPC.id

      # Allow SSH access from anywhere
      ingress {
        from_port   = 22
        to_port     = 22
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      }

      # Allow HTTP access from anywhere
      ingress {
        from_port   = 80
        to_port     = 80
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      }
    }

    # Internet Gateway
    resource "aws_internet_gateway" "TF_IGW" {
      vpc_id = aws_vpc.TF_VPC.id
    }

    # Network Interface
    resource "aws_network_interface" "TF_NI1" {
      subnet_id   = aws_subnet.TF_Subnet1.id
      private_ips = ["170.31.1.5"]
      security_groups = [aws_security_group.TF_SG.id]
    }

    resource "aws_network_interface" "TF_NI2" {
      subnet_id   = aws_subnet.TF_Subnet2.id
      private_ips = ["170.31.2.5"]
      security_groups = [aws_security_group.TF_SG.id]
    }

    # EC2 Instances
    resource "aws_instance" "TF_instance1" {
      ami           = "ami-024e6efaf93d85776"
      instance_type = "t2.micro"
      subnet_id     = aws_subnet.TF_Subnet1.id
      vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.TF_SG.id]
        network_interface {
        network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.TF_NI1.id
        device_index         = 0
      }
    }

    resource "aws_instance" "TF_instance2" {
      ami           = "ami-024e6efaf93d85776"
      instance_type = "t2.micro"
      subnet_id     = aws_subnet.TF_Subnet2.id
      vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.TF_SG.id]
        network_interface {
        network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.TF_NI2.id
        device_index         = 0

      }
    }
```

but I am getting error as below:
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

```
    ╷
    │ Error: Conflicting configuration arguments
    │ 
    │   with aws_instance.TF_instance1,
    │   on main.tf line 74, in resource "aws_instance" "TF_instance1":
    │   74: resource "aws_instance" "TF_instance1" {
    │ 
    │ "network_interface": conflicts with subnet_id
    ╵
    ╷
    │ Error: Conflicting configuration arguments
    │ 
    │   with aws_instance.TF_instance2,
    │   on main.tf line 85, in resource "aws_instance" "TF_instance2":
    │   85: resource "aws_instance" "TF_instance2" {
    │ 
    │ "network_interface": conflicts with subnet_id
```

Comment: Well, the error is pretty clear: you cannot have both `subnet_id` and `network_interface` arguments configured. It's either one or the other. Not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, you need to use either `subnet_id` or `network_interface`. Using `subnet_id` will allocate an ENI in that subnet. When using the `aws_network_interface` you are already specifying the `subnet_id` argument, which means the ENI is already in that subnet. So to fix this, based on the other pieces of code, I think you want this:

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "TF_NI1" {
  subnet_id   = aws_subnet.TF_Subnet1.id
  private_ips = ["170.31.1.5"]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.TF_SG.id]
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "TF_NI2" {
  subnet_id   = aws_subnet.TF_Subnet2.id
  private_ips = ["170.31.2.5"]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.TF_SG.id]
}

# EC2 Instances
resource "aws_instance" "TF_instance1" {
  ami           = "ami-024e6efaf93d85776"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  network_interface {
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.TF_NI1.id
    device_index         = 0
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "TF_instance2" {
  ami           = "ami-024e6efaf93d85776"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  network_interface {
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.TF_NI2.id
    device_index         = 0
  }
}
```

Since I did not find the note about specifying the subnet ID versus network interface in the terraform documentation, the best I could find is this from the [CloudFormation documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-subnetid):

> If you specify a network interface, you must specify any subnets as part of the network interface.

Comment: Error after edit: Error: Conflicting configuration arguments
│ 
│   with aws_instance.TF_instance1,
│   on main.tf line 73, in resource "aws_instance" "TF_instance1":
│   73:     resource "aws_instance" "TF_instance1" {
│ 
│ "network_interface": conflicts with vpc_security_group_ids
╵
╷
│ Error: Conflicting configuration arguments
│ 
│   with aws_instance.TF_instance2,
│   on main.tf line 84, in resource "aws_instance" "TF_instance2":
│   84:     resource "aws_instance" "TF_instance2" {
│ 
│ "network_interface": conflicts with vpc_security_group_ids

Comment: @AbhinavBanerjee Ok, removed the `vpc_security_group_ids` argument in the answer, can you try again.